# Appointments canceled from a series do not appear in the events api as canceled

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

We've implemented a connection to Google's API (GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId) to retrieve events from the Google calendar. Typically, when a series has a canceled event, we receive it as a separate entry with a recurringEventId linking it to the series and canceled status.

However, our client claims that certain meetings within the series have been canceled. Surprisingly, these cancellations aren't recognized as separate events, and there's no exception date in the rule.

We're seeking guidance on how to identify these canceled shows correctly.